# learning flex 4 facing problem with namespaces

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I am trying to learn flex4 from adobe document and I am very confused while using three namespaces.. there is no way i can keep track of when to use what often ending up using fx inside mx or s or similarly making some stupid goofed up combinations of {fx,mx,s}.

Adobe document is huge and i am looking for some good starting point for learning flex .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex.html especially Getting Started part?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite large; however, some basic explanation about the 3 namespaces you've cited:

<fx> tags are typically programmatic functionality and not visual display objects.  You'd use it for declaring a script block in a MXML document or defining variables in a declarative way.

```
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var myVariable:String = "Hello, World!";
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:Object id="variableName"
                   property1="myCustomProperty"
                   property2="anotherCustomProperty" />
    </fx:Declarations>
```

When declaring visual elements and UIComponents on the display list, you'll typically want Spark architecture; therefore, you'd use the Spark namespace.

```
<s:Group />
```

MX architecture is important, but is generally deprecated by Spark.  If a component is available as Spark, you should use that implementation.

```
<mx:Box />
```

All are just packages of the framework, and really no difference than importing packages in ActionScript.  Your custom components will use their package name as a namespace, or you declare a namespace for your Flex MXML library.

If you're using an IDE like Flash Builder, you usually don't have to worry about the namespaces.

In an MXML file, enter the start tag (ie: <), skip the namespace and start typing the class you're after.  In the above examples, I'd hit <s for "script" and the intellisense will show you completion options that will insert the namespace for you.

If the auto completion options do not appear, hit [ctrl]+[space-bar].

Let Flash Builder help with namespaces by completing them for you.

Probably doesn't go far to helping you out, but hopefully this helps a little.

Comment: thanks a lot for such a nice explanation...I have been writing sample codes for a while using flash builder and aware of all these points but the difficulty I am facing is due to deprecation of mx by s and some component are still only in mx (like datagrid ) but then some places it is mentioned that datagrid is only in mx and in some places it is used with s also .. and similarly a list control shud have what component is also a big confusion

Comment: mx:DataGrid was not yet available when Spark architecture was introduced.  Now with Flex 4.5 SDK, the Spark s:DataGrid is available.  Check your Fkex SDK version.  For Spark Lists, you can use item renderers.  With Flash Builder, add an itemRenderer to your List (s:List itemRenderer="") and hit [ctrl]+[space-bar] while in the quotes of the itemRenderer value.  The first option in the auto-completion should be "Create Item Renderer..."  If you select that option Flash Builder will create a new MXML file with the basic boiler plate autogenerated.  Skin classes may be generated as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason but I realized my fault of directly jumping into the reference manual page by page and in over-confidence I ignored the valuable video training sessions..which caused me loss of two weeks, during which i learned stuff but everything was vague like hay-wire but now everything is making sense.